# Using fontspec with LuaLaTeX produces a LaTeX bug message

Tags: fontspec, luatex

I have LuaLaTeX installed via MiKTeX 2.9 on Windows 7. I am trying to use `fontspec` to change my document to a different font than the default CMR fonts. Just invoking `\usepackage{fontspec}` is sufficient to cause the following cryptic error message:

```
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!
! This is a LaTeX bug: check coding!
!
! Command name `\font_set:Nnn' already defined! Current meaning:
!   \protected\long macro:#1#2#3->\tex_font:D #1=#2 at #3\scan_stop:
!
! See the LaTeX3 documentation for further information.
! For immediate help type H .
!...............................................

l.602 \cs_new:Npn \font_set:Nnn
                                #1#2#3 {
?
```

Continuing by hitting return produces a second similar message, and then processing apparently finishes without further fuss or bother.

Is there something I can do about this?

Or do I just have to wait until MiKTeX picks up the next release of LuaLaTex?

Comment: The underlying issue is the same as the one discussed in the question @Sharpie has pointed to. I'd therefore suggest it's a duplicate.

Comment: @Joseph, from the description and answers there, I'd say you are right. My only excuse is that I focused on LuaLaTex and ignored XeTex when searching for the problem before posting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran into this bug a couple of weeks ago and I think the problem is not with LuaLaTeX, but with the `fontspec` package. Try upgrading that package.

See this question concerning the same error message, but produced by XeLaTeX:

> [xelatex compilation error](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13492/xelatex-compilation-error)

Comment: Letting MiKTeX's updater have its way with my install updated about 30 packages including `fontspec`. I can now compile without errors.